# How to disable a tag link in my case

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have something like the following

```
<div class='bar'>                
              <div class='container'>
                        <a class='add' href='#'>Add</a>
                        <a class='remove' href='#'>Remove</a>
             </div>
</div>
```

my jquery

```
  $('.bar').on('click', function(e){

     //do stuff A.   

 })
```

My question is how to prvent `do stuff A` when I click `add` and `remove` `a` tag in my case.

I want `add` and `remove` button doing nothing for now (eventually they will be a link though).

Thanks!

Comment: ...or remove the class from the HTML? But like @codehorse said, commenting it out would be the preferred method.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question completely. Maybe you're after `preventDefault` http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the propagation of event from both `Add` and `Remove` elements by calling `.stopPropagation()`.

```
$('.container a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

or inside the handler check whether the event originated from those elements like

```
$('.bar').on('click', function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('.container a')){
        return
    }

    //do stuff A.   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.bar').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    return false;
});
```